# Accessing variables in closure in R

Tags: r, closures

In the following example, why do `f$i` and `f$get_i()` return different results?

```
factory <- function() {

  my_list <- list()
  my_list$i <- 1

  my_list$increment <- function() {
    my_list$i <<- my_list$i + 1
  }

  my_list$get_i <- function() {
    my_list$i
  }

  my_list
}

f <- factory()

f$increment()
f$get_i() # returns 2
f$i # returns 1
```

Comment: aren't you just changing the value of `my_list$i` but not of `f$i` ? those are not the same variable. If `my_list` existed in global environment, its `i` parameter would be changed but you're not changing any item of `f` object

Comment: Thanks - yes, they are not the same variable, and that's what's surprising. 
 I guess I'm trying to understand _why_ they're not the same variable. The behaviour we see in R is different to what would happen in, say, javascript.

Comment: sorry this is trivial answer but I still think it is the reason: it's just not the same name (though both "represent" the same variable)

Comment: This seems to be related to R's copy by value behaviour, whereby objects (like lists) are always copied rather than passed around by reference.  In many programming languages, `f` and `my_list` would be the same thing (i.e. they would both point to the same location in memory).  In R, it seems that the operation of returning `my_list` from the function `factory` actually makes a copy of it.

Comment: you would love package [tag:data.table] :-) (it is built upon having value "by reference"; this package have a behaviour that can surprise user used to the "copy by value" behaviour ;-) )

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've heard `data.table` relies copy by reference, which I think this is related to the use of `s4` objects.    To be precise, the bit I think that I found confusing about this is that when objects are _returned_ from functions they seem to be duplicated.  I knew that when you pass anything into a function, it makes a copy, but I didn't realise when you return something from a function, it also seems to return a copy, whilst also allowing you to access the original within the function using getters and setters

Comment: it's more that inside function, you work with "temporary" variables, that exist only in the function environment. Actually, you're not supposed to use `<<-` as it can have very undesired behaviour (or at least be quite confusing like in your case).

Comment: If you really want to write Java programs in R, consider using [reference classes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/R5.html) or [R6 classes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you code is very similar to the functional paradigm. R is more often used as a script language. So unless you exactly know what you are doing, it is bad practice to use <<- or to include functions in a functions.

You can find the explanation [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) at the function environment chapter.

Environment is a space/frame where your code is executed. Environment can be nested, in the same way functions are.

When creating a function, you have an enclosure environment attached which can be called by `environment`. This is the enclosing environment.

The function is executed in another environment, the execution environment with the fresh start principle. The execution environment is a children environment of the enclosing environment.

For exemple, on my laptop:

```
> environment()
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> environment(f$increment)
<environment: 0x0000000022365d58>
> environment(f$get_i)
<environment: 0x0000000022365d58>
```

f is an object located in the global environment.

The function `increment` has the enclosing environment 0x0000000022365d58 attached, the execution environment of the function `factory`.

I quote from Hadley:

> When you create a function inside another function, the enclosing
>   environment of the child function is the execution environment of the
>   parent, and the execution environment is no longer ephemeral.

When the function f is executed, the enclosing environments are created with the `my_list` object in it.

That can be assessed with the `ls` command:

```
> ls(envir = environment(f$increment))
[1] "my_list"
> ls(envir = environment(f$get_i))
[1] "my_list"
```

The `<<-` operator is searching in the parents environments for the variables used. In that case, the `my_list` object found is the one in the immediate upper environment which is the enclosing environment of the function.

So when an increment is made, it is made only in that environment and not in the global.

You can see it by replacing the `increment` function by that:

```
  my_list$increment <- function() {
    print("environment")
    print(environment())
    print("Parent environment")
    print(parent.env(environment()))
    my_list$i <<- my_list$i + 1
  }
```

It give me:

```
> f$increment()
[1] "environment"
<environment: 0x0000000013c18538>
[1] "Parent environment"
<environment: 0x0000000022365d58>
```

You can use `get` to access to your result once you have stored the environment name:

```
> my_main_env <- environment(f$increment)
> get("my_list", env = my_main_env)
$i
[1] 2

$increment
function () 
{
    print("environment")
    print(environment())
    print("Parent environment")
    print(parent.env(environment()))
    my_list$i <<- my_list$i + 1
}
<environment: 0x0000000022365d58>

$get_i
function () 
{
    print("environment")
    print(environment())
    print("Parent environment")
    print(parent.env(environment()))
    my_list$i
}
<environment: 0x0000000022365d58>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is the final bit to round out this explanation that 'when `my_list` is returned from `factory` and assigned to `f`, it exists as a list in the global environment and no longer has access to `factory`'s environment (closure). Changes to `factory`'s environment cannot affect `f` because there is no link.  We can still change the `my_list` in `factory`'s environment is through the use of `<<-` within the `my_list$increment` function, but the only way to access to this environment is through an explicit getter function like `my_list$get_i`

Answer (score 6):

```
f <- factory()
```

creates `my_list` object with `my_list$i = 1` and assigns it to `f`. So now `f$i = 1`.

```
f$increment()
```

increments `my_list$i` only. It does not affect `f`.

Now

```
f$get_i()
```

returns (previously incremented) `my_list$i` while

```
f$i
```

returns unaffected `f$i`

It' because you used `<<-` operator that operates on global objects. If you change your code to

```
my_list$increment <- function(inverse) {
    my_list$i <- my_list$i + 1
}
```

`my_list` will be incremented only inside `increment` function. So now you get

```
> f$get_i() 
[1] 1
> f$i 
[1] 1
```

Let me add a one more line to your code, so we could see `increment`'s intestines:

```
 my_list$increment <- function(inverse) {
    my_list$i <- my_list$i + 1
    return(my_list$i)
  }
```

Now, you can see that `<-` operates only inside `increment` while `<<-` operated outside of it.

```
> f <- factory()
> f$increment()
[1] 2
> f$get_i() 
[1] 1
> f$i
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand that `f$increment() ` affects `my_list` and not `f`, but I don't know why.  The `my_list` within the closure is a different `my_list` to that which is returned (and then assigned to `f`).  Is this because R always uses reference by value, so what is returned by the `factory` function is not a reference to `my_list` in the closure, but a copy of `my_list`?

Comment: The next question could probably be - how to have a truly "global" `my_list$i` inside `f`.

Comment: I don't know how. I don't know what for. :)

Comment: I understand that `<<-` searches in the environment 'one level up' from the function.  So in the original code `my_list$i <<- my_list$i + 1` means that the `increment` function can access the `my_list` variable in the scope of the `factory` function.  I guess the bit I don't really understand is _why_ ' `f$increment() ` increments my_list$i only. It does not affect f.'

Comment: `increment` increments `my_list$i` and `f` does not  hold any `my_list` object (see `str(f)`). So from `my_list`'s point of view, `f` is not 'one level up' from the `increment` function

Answer (score 4):

Based on comments from @Cath on "value by reference", I was inspired to come up with this.

```
library(data.table)
factory <- function() {
   my_list <- list()
   my_list$i <- data.table(1)

   my_list$increment <- function(inverse) {
     my_list$i[ j = V1:=V1+1]
  }

   my_list$get_i <- function() {
     my_list$i
   }
   my_list
 }
f <- factory()
f$increment()
f$get_i() # returns 2
   V1
1:  2
f$i # returns 1
   V1
1:  2
f$increment()
f$get_i() # returns 2
   V1
1:  3
f$i # returns 1
   V1
1:  3
```